# How can I remove the window padding on GTK3 apps in Awesome-WM?

Tags: gnome3, awesome, window-management, window-decorations, gtk3

I use [awesome](/questions/tagged/awesome) in a tiling mode for almost all my desktops. Since the advent of client side decorations in GTK3 some common Gnome project apps have taken to giving themselves a generous amount of padding outside of their main window border. I suspect this is for shadow effects, but it wreaks havok with the tiling system as the window sizing is done based on the padded size, not the normal window itself.

Notable offenders are nautilus and gedit, but other recently updated Gnome apps all have the some behavior.

[image: screenshot]

How can I configure GTK and/or AwesomeWM to ignore these paddings and size the windows based on the actual window geometry? The result I want is a zero-border, zero-padding tiled layout.

Comment: Will http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/how-to-disable-gtk3-client-side.html help?

Comment: @DKBose I don't think that's the right track as it's not actually the decorations in my case that are an issue. I don't have or want any decorations at all, so what is shown in that article as "incorrect display" is actually exactly what I'm going for---no decorations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```
.window-frame {
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

(via https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1416334#p1416334)

I had to restart X for it to take effect - SIGHUP awesome was not sufficient.

Comment: That did the trick. Now I'm scared! Since when did the window properties start getting defined in CSS?

Comment: I just died a little inside.